# Changing value of a Java variable from outside the running process

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Java program performing some large analysis tasks, running through a loop (essentially 24/7) in one thread and accessing a number of other threads to do parallel processing.  I am presently configuring the number of other active threads to send tasks to using a constant.  During the day, I like to set this to a smaller value (say, 4) to leave some of my machine's resources available for my interactive use.  Overnight (or other times I leave my machine unattended) I would like the program to use a larger number of threads (say, 8).   Currently I am halting the program, changing the constant, rebuilding, and restarting the program (I have to restart all 8 threads).  This is becoming tedious to do on a regular basis.

I would like to set up a simple system to type a single command/script from outside Java to change the program's behavior, so that it can remain running but vary the number of idle threads based on my input.   I have searched SO for answers and know that this is apparently not possible with an Environment variable.   I can think of two possibilities:  set a value in a text file and read that in each cycle of the loop; and store a value in the MySQL db that my program interacts with.

While these solutions would work for me, I am interested in knowing if there are any other (more standard?) ways of having Java "configuration variables" accessible from outside the running process.

If it's relevant, I'm running the processes from within Eclipse.

Edit:  Just thought of another possibility:  USR1 and USR2 signals...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an additional thread that was always waiting for a connection on a particular port, and write a simple program to send a message to the program on that port (probably just from localhost). On receiving this message, the program could change whatever settings it wanted.

Comment: That's ... exactly what JMX gives you, and more.

Comment: Interesting idea. The main thread is already running a webserver process on port 8800 so I could play with interpreting those requests.

Comment: "Why didn't you list that as one of our assets?!" - The Princess Bride :)

Comment: It also has a holocaust cloak!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for JMX:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/index.html
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jmx.html (example code)

If you don't want to go all out with that, you can use a `.properties` file that your process reads at startup for its configuration. Have a thread monitor the file for changes, and when it does change (because you edited it), re-read it and change your program's behavior accordingly. (Java 7 has File monitoring built in, prior versions you have to code it up yourself but can find examples on the web)

Comment: Yes, the file monitoring/read is the solution I'm already leaning toward but was hoping for something less kludgy.  JMX looks neat but probably overkill for what is really just personal convenience.

Comment: The Spring framework makes JMX fairly trivial to implement via annotions, such as @ManagedResource